# How to build a API service that has a single url but multiple versions of application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here is my situation:
There is a API service and it'll publish a new version once a season.
I create a web application for each version. So there's a list of web applications under default website that looks like:

- API_2016S1
- API_2016S2
- API_2016S3
- ...

For clients, the url of API should be the same, even its version has been changed.
The version info won't be a part of the API url.
And the relationship between client and API version is storing in a database.

So the flow of a client's request may looks like:

- client
- send request(with client id in the header and session's cookie)
- a portal application that do:

  - authentication
  - determine which API application should be
  - send client's request to specific API application
- specific API application do:

  - receives request(regardless of authentication)
  - process request
  - response to portal application
- the portal application responses to client

So for the upcoming new version of API service, I just need to create web applications for them and setting relationships in the database.

For now I'm trying to build the portal application by myself.
My question is: Is there any similar structure or mechanism can handle this kind situation? Or any idea for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called API Gateway or API Middleware. Instead of sending requests to the actual APIs, all clients send those requests to this middleware and it serves as a proxy and forwards the requests to a correct APIs.
There are some open source solutions such as [KONG](https://getkong.org/), [Tyk](https://tyk.io/) (and others ) that you can deploy and manage by yourself or you can consider [AWS API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) as a managed service.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I'm looking for API gateway now.